# Where are access and refresh tokens stored in the backend?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, server

I'm creating a web application that requires user authentication and was wondering where I should store Bearer and refresh tokens. Should I store these in the database? I read somewhere that isn't safe, but I don't really see an alternative, given I need to preserve this data for when a client makes requests and the request needs to be authorized.

Thanks!